# what does the '@' sign at the begging of field name in ElasticSearch means?

Tags: elasticsearch

for example, what are the differences in the following 3 field names?

```
mappings = {
    "properties": {

        "@timestamp": {"type": "date"},

or
        "timestamp": {"type": "date"},
or
        "_timestamp": {"type": "date"},

    }
}
```

not sure if the following usage still supported.

```
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

"@timestamp" and "timestamp", what's use case for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convention used in Logstash, as metadata fields, you can use both:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata